# Downloading file with Python mechanize

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

I am trying to download a file from a website using python and mechanize. My current code successfully logs on to the website and opens the page that contains the download link.

The download link is: https://www.lendingclub.com/browse/browseNotesRawDataV2.action

The info for the link is:

```
Link(base_url='https://www.lendingclub.com/browse/browse.action', url='/browse/browseNotesRawDataV2.action', text='', tag='a', attrs=[('class', 'master_pngfix'), ('id', 'browseDownloadAllLink'), ('href', '/browse/browseNotesRawDataV2.action')])
```

I use the follow_link method to click on the link:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.follow_link(url='/browse/browseNotesRawDataV2.action')
```

However, nothing happens and no file is downloaded. When I open the link in my browser when I'm logged on, it pauses for a few seconds and downloads the file.

How can I download the file using Python?

Comment: Did you enable logging? Anything you've seen there? Did you try "retrieve" instead of follow_link?

Comment: How do you enable logging? I'm using Eclipse on a mac. I tried retrieve and nothing happened. Is there some way to indicate a filename to save as?

Comment: You can turn on logging with `import logging; logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)`

Comment: I turned on logging but I don't see any errors.

Comment: What else do you see in the log? Any HTTP 404, 403, 500 errors? Does it say anything about a file beeing downloaded?. As for the parameters, you can look them up using `pydoc mechanize` or `help(mechanize.Browser.retrieve)` from an interactive python shell.

Comment: I had to enable logging manually in Eclipse. The file was being stored  in a temp location, so I just added this code to give it a filename:

    `br.retrieve('https://www.lendingclub.com/browse/browseNotesRawDataV2.action','loans.csv')[0]`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For anyone who's interested, this was the solution:

```
br.retrieve('https://www.lendingclub.com/browse/browseNotesRawDataV2.action','l‌​oans.csv')[0]
```

Comment: Just to follow up on @user1137778's answer, make sure to provide the filename (the second argument in the example), otherwise, a temporary file is created and subsequently deleted. For example,
br.retrieve(yourcustomurl, f'{yourcustomfilename}.mp3')[0]